# How to change `cache` and `ajaxOptions` when upgrading to jQuery UI 1.10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, upgrade, jquery-ui-tabs

Since I upgraded to jQuery UI 1.10 something has changed. Before that upgrade, code related to my [jQuery UI Tab](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) was the following:

```
$('.selector').tabs({
  cache: true,
  ajaxOptions: {
    dataType: 'html'
  }
 });
```

As wrote in the [jQuery UI 1.10 Upgrade Guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-use-beforeload-event), both `cache` and `ajaxOptions` has been removed. The guide also states to use the `beforeLoad` event, but how can I upgrade the code as well?

Answer (score 3):

A working approach is:

```
$(".selector").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
        if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
        ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
          ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
        });
    }
});
```

Source: https://github.com/jquery/jqueryui.com/blob/master/page/upgrade-guide/1.9.md#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event