# ajaxOptions is deprecated, what's the alternative for displaying error message when trying to connect to database?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This was the way before if I wanted to display an error message for no connection:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions:{
            error: function(xhr,status,index,anchor){
                $(anchor.hash).html('Could not connect to server')
            }
        }
});
```

But now ajaxOptions is deprecated in favor of `beforeLoad` according to API document. How should the same effect be achieved? Suppose I have a tab that connects to a php file situated on the server, and when there is no connection it displays

> "Could not connect to server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually an example of this on the [jQueryUI tabs examples page](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax). Something like this should work:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
            ui.panel.html(
                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
        });
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WP29E/146/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post [How to change `cache` and `ajaxOptions` when upgrading to jQuery UI 1.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856795/how-to-change-cache-and-ajaxoptions-when-upgrading-to-jquery-ui-1-10)

Add success and event handlers to your ui.jqXHR object.